# Get contributions in Gitlab

Tags: git, github, graphql, gitlab

Currently in github I am able to get my contributions for the last year using the GraphQL API.

```
{
  user(login: "username") {
    contributionsCollection {
      contributionCalendar {
        weeks {
          contributionDays {
            contributionCount
            date
            color
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I was not able to find the equivalent in gitlab GraphQL API. Is it possible to have this information in gitlab? Even that it is not using the GraphQL it is ok, just would like to be able to collect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a user’s contributions from the events API:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/events.html#get-user-contribution-events

```
https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/users/:id/events
```

You can also get a JSON representation of the recent contributions for a user at the user’s page

```
https://gitlab.example.com/users/:username/calendar.json
```

Comment: I think that this will not work, because it will not show contributions that are private, right? In github API it will return if the user had opted to show it, but will not specify what was, which is fine for my case.

Comment: Also, were not able to find the documentation for the second one, is there any link?

Comment: The second, public 'recent contributions' link you mentioned seems to be inaccurate or obsolete as of now.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#new-graphql-api-for-contribution-analytics) (November 2022) proposes an alternative, but only for Premium/Ultimate.

> ### New GraphQL API for Contribution Analytics
>
> To help you analyze team contributions, we have now exposed the Contribution Analytics data through GraphQL. Using this [new API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/graphql/reference/index.html#groupcontributions), you can identify opportunities for improvement and gain insights into the top contributors in your team.
>
> The [Contribution Analytics](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/contribution_analytics/index.html) report visualizes the team’s push events, merge requests, and opened or closed issues at a group level over time.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_6/ca_gql.gif -- New GraphQL API for Contribution Analytics]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/contribution_analytics/index.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/375995).